# @Value from application.properties in SpringBoot gives null all the time

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, components

How to properly inject value from application.properties file?

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class,args);
    }
```

application.properties file:

```
my.password=admin
```

test class:

```
@Component
public class Test {
    @Value("${my.password}")
    private String mypassword;

    public String getMypassword() {
        return mypassword;
    }

    public void setMypassword(String mypassword) {
        this.mypassword = mypassword;
    }

    public Test(){
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+ mypassword);
    }
}
```

Console prints always null, not the value from `application` file

Comment: I dont think that the Value tag assigns the value before the constructor is called. I could be wrong, but use the PostConstruct tag on a new function and print the value, see if that works.

Comment: u are right, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are not injected when the class is being created (i.e when your constructor is called), but a bit later. Hence you see null in the constructor.

Try adding a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` like this and check the result:

```
@PostConstruct
public void afterCreation(){
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+ mypassword);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I have another problem. It works with @PostConstruct, but when I am trying to create Test t = new Test(); and call afterCreation() it prints null again. Is there another way of creating objects in springboot? Beacuse I also tried "@"Autowired Test t; and then call foobar() but I got nullpointer exception

Comment: When you do new, then what you are creating a new object. and not a spring bean. hence `@value` or any spring annotations doesnt have any meaning, hence null. In spring environment doing `new` is a crime :)

Comment: Thanks, but how am I supposed to create objects then?I thought that I can call @Autowired on my "@"Components. But I am left with nullpointers.

Comment: can you post an example of what u r describing. if your class is a bean (has one of these annotations @component, @service, ....) then autowiring should not be null, provided the class you are using `@autowired` is also a bean.

Comment: I will post it in the answer shortly, but the problem might be in @bean part beacuse I am just using "@"Component

Answer (score 0):

@pvpkiran I am trying to add this to my main method, rest is unchanged.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    static Test  t;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);

        t.foobar();
    }
}
```

Comment: I realise I might be doing some spring heresy right now, but Can someone be so kind and show me an example of Creating object using @Autowired and calling its method somewhere in the code? I cant find it anywhere.